# Advantage / Disadvantages of having custom layout code in -[UIViewController viewDidLayoutSubviews]

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller

Why do so many sources recommend `-[UIViewController viewDidLayoutSubviews]` over `-[UIViewController viewWillLayoutSubviews]` as the view life-cycle method in which to implement custom layout?

The Apple documentation mentions that either method is a good choice for implementing custom layout, however it does not mention why you might use one over the other.

I gather one reason is that autolayout has had a chance to go over everything already by the time `-[UIViewController viewDidLayoutSubviews]` is called.

Is there a simple example of when laying views out in `-[UIViewController viewWillLayoutSubviews]` is too soon, but in `-[UIViewController viewDidLayoutSubviews]` is just right?

If I am avoiding explicitly using autolayout (just using autoresizing masks which translate to constraints), I'm wondering if I might as well position views in `-[UIViewController viewWillLayoutSubviews]`, as it occurs sooner.